# Entity Framework base property mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Hello I have a problem with my mapping.

I have classes in hierarchical structure:

1. TaxYear
2. Owner
3. EconomyUnit
4. Report
5. ReportItem
6. Invoice

All this classes have a base class "BaseEntity" and a parent property and parent_id property.

The invoice parent property is not from type "ReportItem" because "Onwer" has a seperate invoice list so the type is "BaseEntity".

This works fine I can use as parent "ReportItem" and "Owner".

But now I want to "move" the invoices between parents. At this moment only from "ReportItem" to "ReportItem".

Set the new parent:

```
foreach (var invoice in oldReportItem.Invoices)
{
    invoice.Parent = newReportItem;
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This works without errors but not correctly. EF created three columns for my parent property.

- Owner_Id
- ReportItem_Id
- Parent_Id

If you insert a invoice then both columns will get the same Id. Works fine but if you set a new parent then "Onwer_Id" or ReportItem_Id will be set to null and Parent_Id will only be updated.

There is my problem. I think my mapping is wrong. Can anyone help me?

Fluent-Api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportItem>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Items)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

BaseEntity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public abstract String GetName();

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity DeepCopy()
    {
        return (BaseEntity)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Owner:

```
public class Owner : BaseEntity
{
    public Owner()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<EconomyUnit>();
        PrivateInvoices = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
    }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TaxYear Year { get; set; }
    public Guid? YearId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EconomyUnit> Items { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Invoice> PrivateInvoices { get; private set; }

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

ReportItem:

```
public class ReportItem : BaseEntity
{
    public ReportItem()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
    }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Invoice> Items { get; private set; }

    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Report Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Invoice:

```
public class Invoice: BaseEntity
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Thank you
Lyror

Comment: I think for EF to load that properly, it needs to know the difference between Owners and ReportItems since they are not stored in the same table. Maybe the invoice object needs to have a ReportItem optional Parent and an optional owner, one will always be null

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with the OP.

> I have classes in hierarchical structure:
>
> TaxYear Owner EconomyUnit Report ReportItem Invoice

Your class structures indicate that TaxYear is optional so it cannot be a parent (by definition).  Some of your classes are missing so I cannot determine if any other relationships are flawed.  Taking your statement at face value, your classes would be more like this (extraneous fields removed for clarity)

```
public abstract class BaseEntity - Unchanged

public class Owner : BaseEntity
{
    // Parent navigation    
    public Guid YearId { get; set; }
    public virtual TaxYear Year { get; set; }

    // Child navigation
    public virtual ICollection<EconomyUnit> Units { get; private set; }
}

public class EconomicUnit : BaseEntity
{
    // Parent navigation    
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }

    // Child navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Report> Reports { get; private set; }
}

public class Report : BaseEntity
{
    // Parent navigation    
    public Guid UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual EconomicUnit Unit { get; set; }

    // Child navigation    
    public virtual ICollection<ReportItem> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class ReportItem : BaseEntity
{
    // Parent navigation    
    public Guid ReportId { get; set; }
    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }

    // Child navigation    
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; private set; }
}

public class Invoice : BaseEntity
{
    // Parent navigation    
    public Guid ReportItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportItem ReportItem { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to see a list of Invoices for an Owner, try this on:

```
dbContext.Invoices.Where(a => a.ReportItem.Report.EconomicUnit.Owner.Id == <parameter>).Include(b => b.ReportItem.Report.EconomicUnit.Owner.TaxYear).ToList();
```

Of course, you can select into a new DTO object inverting the relationship Owner ==> Invoices.